# How to implement a concurrency counter in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get a concurrency counter work in EF Core. Say if somebody triggered my counter, I would run this SQL to record it.

```
UPDATE my_counter_table 
SET some_count = some_count + 1 
WHERE id = 42;
```

Currently I'm using NpgSQL for EF Core, and I can do the same thing with:

```cs
var counter = dbContext.MyCounterTable.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == 42);
counter.someCount++;
dbContext.Update(counter);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

However, if someCount was 99, then the generated SQL will be:

```
UPDATE my_counter_table 
SET some_count = 100, other_column = 123 
WHERE id = 42;
```

It seems I have to deal with concurrency conflict then, and other column has to be updated even no changes were applied, which is grossly inefficient.

Is there a simple way to implement a concurrency counter? Or `ExecuteSqlRaw` is preferred?

Comment: Have you considered using Posgres' `xmin` instead of implementing your own column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, in EF Core 7.0 we have `ExecuteUpdate` , which can reference the existing property value in the update statement.

```cs
context.Blogs
    .Where(b => b.Rating < 3)
    .ExecuteUpdate(setters => setters.SetProperty(b => b.Rating, b => b.Rating + 1));
```

will produces:

```sql
UPDATE [b]
SET [b].[Rating] = [b].[Rating] + 1
FROM [Blogs] AS [b]
WHERE [b].[Rating] < 3
```

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete#referencing-the-existing-property-value

Comment: I'm not convinced this approach is actually concurrency-safe under all circumstances. For example, do you know what kind of transaction isolation level this will run under?